# angular.js $http.post sends data to Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

When I am making a post request from angular to create session

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions',                
            {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(status);
            });
};
```

It is receiving as JSON but **params** converts into hash in rails, so how to get values of email and password?

```
Started POST "/api/v1/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-25 21:21:56+0530
Processing by Api::V1::SessionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"{\"email\":\"hello@example.com\",\"password\":\"somepassword123\"}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

As i see the params content now - it is as

```
"{\"email\":\"hello@example.com\",\"password\":\"somepassword123\"}"=>"[FILTERED]"}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    }).success(function(response){
        // do something
    }).error(function(error){
        // do something
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using jQuery:

```
  var myDataOfServer = $.param({'disappeared':{
               name:$scope.data.name ... }
```

`$.param` is responsible  of cause parsing JSON for serve side.

Answer (score -1):

is necessary implement module in angular for ruby ?

My server Ruby is one Web Service.

My IONIC is client...

My create http.post method is doing this:

Parameters: {"{\"name\":\"ola mundo\"}"=>nil}

but should be:

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"l916wPHn7wvf0LzEPclKBHALEE7j9KjyiUc5aMpatSFqyQGsmCLwN9ByT8gpwrcrEgC3MLRcafQWSc3V6bvAZA==", "disappeared"=>{"name"=>"nome"}, "commit"=>"saved"}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer is not clear. Try editing your answer to make your intentions more understandable to those coming across your answer in the future.